# Creating a JSON object without multiple SQL queries (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm trying to create this kind of JSON object by using MySQL/ PHP.

```
[ 
{
  "hours":0
  "vulnerability":867
  "file":166
  "virus":59
}, 
{
  "hours":1
  "vulnerability":400
  "file":14
  "virus":40
}, 
]
```

I'm trying to reduce the amount of queries sent to the server as my db scales quite large. My query returns these results:

[image: SQL data]

So while looping through the data I'm getting this kind of JSON returned:

```
{
  "hours":0
  "vulnerability":867
}, 
{
  "hours":0
  "file":14
}, 
{
  "hours":0
  "virus":59
}, 
]
```

I would like to create the desired output without using multiple SQL queries in a foreach loop. Full code below-

```
$query = "SELECT hour(generated_time) as hours, subtype, count(subtype) as y from description group by subtype, hours order by hours asc, y desc";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$output = array();
$data = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data["time"] => $row['hours'];
    $data[$row['subtype']] => $row['y'];
    array_push($output, $data);
}

echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: Please, **DO NOT** use `mysql_query` in new applications. It's deprecated, dangerous if you're not careful to [properly escape](http://bobby-tables.com/php) every value you put in your query, and is being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) outlines the recommended best practices.

Comment: I don't really know what you're representing with this data but it seems you are using an [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) model which might be much more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: +1 tadman - Thanks for this, this won't be going into production, it's a personal project, but thanks anyway, will look into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run the SQL query once, and loop over the results and put each row in its correct spot.

Something like this:

```
$output = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $key = intval($row['hours']);
    if(!isset($output[$key])){
        $output[$key] = array('hours' => $key);
    }
    $output[$key][$row['subtype']] = intval($row['y']);
}

echo json_encode($output);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know all of the subtypes ahead of time you can rewrite the query to format the data the way you want it:

```
SELECT
    hour(generated_time) as hours,
    SUM(subtype = "vulnerability") AS vulnerability,
    SUM(subtype = "file") AS file,
    SUM(subtype = "virus") AS virus
FROM
    description
GROUP BY hours
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but the subtypes are chosen on the fly. +1

Answer (score 0):

It is only one mySQL query.  It is put into the associative array and the loop isn't calling more mySQL queries but instead looking through the entry in the associative array in the loop.

Comment: Should this be a comment?